# Should "promotions" and "relegations" tags be combined?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, there are two tags related to the promotion and relegation systems of some sports organizations: [promotions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotions) and [relegations](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relegations).  There are 4 questions tagged with both tags, and one question tagged with only the [promotions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotions) tag, although it could easily be tagged with both tags.

Do we need two tags for this?  I would think that a combined tag called [promotion-relegation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotion-relegation) would be better.

Comment: FYI, the two rugby questions under said tags were its introduction. If promotions and relegations go hand-in-hand in which one cannot ask a question about promotions without asking relegations, then I agree with you. However, I am not aware if that would be the case or not. As far as the tag request, I'm open to the combined tag if necessary.

Comment: A question with only the `relegations` tag has come up. This would lead me to believe to keep the two tags separated. https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/why-the-ipl-teams-dont-have-any-english-cricketers

Comment: @edmastermind29 I see that, but I don't understand how the "relegations" tag applies to [that question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/4803/1723).

Comment: May be worth requesting clarification...